# Can't save changes to edit of a Django ModelForm blog; form reverts to previous state

Tags: django-forms

I read through two other posts related to this topic but could not glean any solutions to my issue -- I can't seem to get the edit_post form(edit_post.html) to save changes made to the form and either redirect back to the index page or render the page with edits saved. After clicking the "Save changes" button, the form reverts back to the previous pre-filled instance state before edits were made.

This is exercise 19-1 from Python Crash Course:

> **19-1. Blog:** Start a new Django project called Blog. Create an app called blogs
> in the project and a model called BlogPost. The model should have fields like
> title, text, and
> date_added. Create a superuser for the project, and use the
> admin site to make a couple of short posts. Make a home page that shows all
> posts in chronological order.
> Create a form for making new posts and another for editing existing posts.
> Fill in your forms to make sure they work.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Blog_post(models.Model):
    """A blogpost posted by a User"""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return f"{self.title}\n{self.body}"
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Blog_post

class NewPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog_post
        fields = ['body', 'title']
        labels = {'body': '', 'title': "Title:"}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Blog_post
from .forms import NewPostForm

def index(request):
    """The home page for Blog."""
    posts = Blog_post.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'blogs/index.html', context)

def new_post(request):
    """Add a new blogpost."""

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = NewPostForm()

    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = NewPostForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('blogs:index')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/new_post.html', context)

def edit_post(request, post_id):
    """Edit an existing post."""
    post = Blog_post.objects.get(id=post_id)

    if request != 'POST':
        form = NewPostForm(instance=post)

    else:
        form = NewPostForm(instance=post, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blogs:index', post_id=post.id)

    context = {'post': post, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/edit_post.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blogs'

urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    # Page for adding a new blogpost
    path('new_post/', views.new_post, name='new_post'),

    # Page for editing an entry.
    path('edit_post/<int:post_id>/', views.edit_post, name='edit_post'),
]
```

index.html

```
{% extends "blogs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p> This is the Blog project exercise 19-1 on pg 421 of Python Crash Course.</p>

<p> Blogposts: </p>
<ul>
  {% for post in posts %}
    <li>
      <p>{{ post.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }} - {{ post }} -
        <a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post.id %}">Edit Post</a>
      </p>
    </li>
  {% empty %}
    <li> No topics have been added yet. </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'blogs:new_post' %}">Add a new blogpost.</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

edit_post.html

```
{% extends "blogs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>{{ post }}</p>

  <p>Edit post:</p>

  <form action="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post.id %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Save changes</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in the `edit_post()` view function. Here's the first part of the if block:

```py
    if request != 'POST':
        form = NewPostForm(instance=post)
```

I believe that should be:

```py
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = NewPostForm(instance=post)
```

This is checking if the request method is `POST`. You left off the `.method` part of `request.method`. The request object itself will never be `'POST'`, so this block is always running even when the request method is POST.

I believe if you change `request` to `request.method` in the if block, you will be able to edit posts.